# Pressing ALT key in LyX causes command Bar

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, keyboard

I'm working in LyX (in Ubuntu 14.10) and I'm trying to use simple math macros using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>*XX*</kbd> combination, where *XX* could be anything, such as <kbd>F</kbd> for a fraction or <kbd>(</kbd> for parentheses.

However, as soon as I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key, a LyX command line comes up, which doesn't let me use any of these macros. This happens whether I am in a math environment or not.

I'm sure there's an easy way to turn this off, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Alt + X should be the shortcut for opening the minibuffer. Go to Tools --> Preferences --> Editing --> Shortcuts, and check which shortcut is set for `command-execute`.

Comment: I think you are referring to the Unity menu prompt. A work around is to do the alt+m sequence slightly slower than usual. So do <hold alt>, press <M>, release <M>, wait one second, release <alt>. Regardless of whether you're satisfied with this work around, can you confirm whether that works so we know if that is indeed what you're talking about? Another fix is to disable the HUD. See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply, have been preparing for exams. My command-execute setting is indeed set to ALT + X. scottkosty's suggestion is a workaround I could definitely live with, and the provided link is a good way to do address the underlying issue.

Comment: Apologies as I'm new to the site. What is proper procedure? Should I create an answer to this question myself?

Comment: No, I think @scottkosty should post his comment as an answer, so you can mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to the Unity menu prompt. A work around is to do the alt+m sequence slightly slower than usual. So do , press , release , wait one second, release . Regardless of whether you're satisfied with this work around, can you confirm whether that works so we know if that is indeed what you're talking about? Another fix is to disable the HUD. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key